# Efficient algorithm to randomly find available places inside a list in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, python-2.7

I need to **randomly** assign a place inside a list to an input. I need to check whether it is not occupied first and then use it. The best algorithm that I can come up with is the following:

```
def get_random_addr(input_arr):

    while True:
        addr = random.randrange(1, len(input_arr))
        if input_arr[addr] is None:
            break
    return addr
```

This is obviously not efficient since as we occupy more slots, the loop takes longer to find an empty slot, and even it may take forever (suppose only one empty slot is left). Do you have any better solutions?

**How I did it**

Based on the chosen answer, this is how I ended up doing it. It is very fast and efficient compared to the solutions which search through the whole list and find the `None` elements and randomly choose from the retrieved set. I think the bottleneck was `random.choice` method which seems to be very slow.

```
# Create a list of indexes at the beginning when all the values are None 
available_index = list(range(1, len(input_arr)))
random.shuffle(available_index)

# To get a random index simply pop from shuffled available index
random_index = available_index.pop()
```

While this method has extra O(n) memory complexity, in practice it is very efficient and fast.

Comment: If you really want to do this efficiently, use `numpy`.  Otherwise, keep a list of all `None` indices, by looping once, then just pop from that list and assign your value

Comment: under the hood numpy still is `O(N)` its just a faster `O(N)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can't use numpy I'd keep a set of indexes which are known to contain `None`. Every time `None` is added or removed this set of indexes will be updated

Comment: this is a good answer(+1) ... but i dont think numpy solves it for him ... we think of numpy vector operations as O(1) but `A[A==None]` is still `O(N)` under the hood ... the set of known empties is the right answer though i think

Comment: @JoranBeasley `numpy` is indeed `O(N)` (it is still not using magic :) ) however `numpy`'s under-the-hood-loops are faster (sometimes in several orders of magnitudes)

Answer (score 0):

Your function can take arbitrarly long to return. In particular, you will get into an infinite loop if no item is `None`.

Instead, recover all indices which are `None` and use `random.choices` to randomly return `k` of them.

```
import random

def get_random_addr(input_arr, k=1, target=None):
    return random.choices([i for i, v in enumerate(input_arr) if v is target], k=k)
```

#### Usage

```
l = [0, None, 2, 3, None, None]

for i in get_random_addr(l, k=2):
    l[i] = i

print(l) # [0, None, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: In the long run this is as inefficient as OP's code

Comment: `none_index` should be something that's only calculated once, not each call

Comment: @DeepSpace No because OP's answer may choose an index which is not None while this will not

Comment: @OlivierMelançon True, but this code is O(N) as well (it has to iterate over the whole list). BTW, I believe you meant to iterate over `enumerate(input_arr)`

Comment: @DeepSpace There is no way not to iterate over the list. You solution omits the fact that if you keep a set of available indices, you add an O(1) operation on every item setting. Depending on which operation is most often used, this could be longer

Comment: The difference is that this answer iterates *each time* an index needs to be chosen.  Instead, if you calculate this list once, and just pop from it when you need a random index, you avoid another O(N) operation.

Comment: @OlivierMelançon 1. I don't see how it can be longer. In the worst case it'd be the same.  2. I believe (correct me if I'm wrong) that `append` and `remove` are implemented in C. These C iterations are faster than the Python iteration your code is doing every time a random empty index is requested

Comment: @DeepSpace I added a solution based on shuffle in case we know multiple insertions in a row are necessary

Comment: @OlivierMelançon Which only added more time complexity :(

Comment: @DeepSpace There is no usecase, we cannot know.

Comment: @DeepSpace I'll give you an example of what I mean by 'could be longer'. Take Python's len function. It is known to be O(1). Although it is O(1) due to the fact that an O(1) operation was added to every insertion and removal from the list. While this is a good thing if you ever want to acces the lenght, any code that only does insertion, n of them, will be longer by a factor of O(n) (that is by a cosntant in that case). This is what I mean by: we cannot know without a usecase, it's a tradeoff.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `enumerate` to index your list first, filter out those that are `None`, and then use `random.choice` to pick an available space.

```
from random import choice
def get_random_addr(input_arr):
    return choice([index for index, value in enumerate(input_arr) if value is None])
print(get_random_addr([None, 1, None, 2]))
```

This outputs either `0` or `2` randomly, or `None` if there is no more space available.

Comment: This solution slows down my code significantly! I'm dealing with pretty large lists and the code just halted at this line! Not sure why tho!

Comment: @A23149577 It's because I used a lambda function as a filter, which is inefficient in python. I've edited my answer to use list comprehension instead. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Well, it is still notably slower than my naive solution, but I think that's the cost I should pay to avoid infinite loop.

Comment: @A23149577 Your naive solution would certainly be faster when there are plenty of space available, since you don't have to scan through the entire list for available spaces first. But as you also realized, your solution would be much slower when there is less space left, so scanning for available spaces is simply a necessary evil for a predictable performance.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to DeepSpace's idea, except with `O(1)` memory and `O(n)` time, but faster by a constant factor since it only iterates over half the slots in the array.

1. Keep track of the number of empty slots.
2. Iterate through the list.
3. If a slot is empty, return your new value with probability `1/number_empty_slots`
4. If we did not return and the slot is empty, redistribute probability mass over other empty slots

Code:

```
def get_random_addr(input_arr, num_empty_slots):
    # num_empty_slots contains the number of empty slots in input_arr
    for index, elem in enumerate(arr): 
        if elem is None: 
            if random.random() < 1 / num_empty_slots:
                return index
            num_empty_slots -= 1
```

Answer (score 0):

In my approach, I pick an arbitrary address in the target array, and if it is free I add it to the output list, but if it is not, I map that address to an address which does contain `None`, nearest to the end of the list. All entries in the array beyond and including this mapped free address are dropped from this list, since they are either nonempty, or already are represented elsewhere in the list. I repeat this process, chopping away at the size of the target list, making it easier and easier to find new empty addresses as it proceeds. There's a few other minor details to make it all work, but I think the code below can explain those better than I can with words.

```
from random import random

def randint(max_val):
    return int(random() * max_val)

def assign(values, target):
    output = []
    mapping = dict()
    mmax = 0
    size = len(target)
    for val in values:
        idx = randint(size)
        while target[idx] != None:
            if idx in mapping:
                idx = mapping.pop(idx)
                mmax = max(mapping or [0])
                break

            min_size = max(idx, mmax)
            try:
                size -= target[size-1:min_size:-1].index(None)
            except:
                size = min_size + 1

            if target[size-1] == None:
                size -= 1
                mapping[idx] = size
                if idx > mmax:
                    mmax = idx
            elif size-1 in mapping:
                size -= 1
                mapping[idx] = mapping.pop(size)
                mmax = max(mapping or [0])

            idx = randint(size)
        target[idx] = val
        output.append(idx)
    return output
```

Note that this modifies the target list passed to it. If you don't want to modify it, you really have two options: implement a bit of extra logic to check if the "free" address is already consumed, or copy the entire list (in which case, reverse it and patch the indices, so that the `.index()` can work on the list directly, which is the major time sink anyways.

I'd also recommend verifying that the solutions it produces are valid. I've done some testing on my part, but I very well could have missed something.